# How to save a webpage table parsed with HAP to a text file with same layout as webpage?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I been using HAP to parse my table, and it is showing up perfectly the way I want it in the webpage using this code..

```
foreach(var table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
    //Response.Write("Found: " + table.Id);
    foreach(HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        Response.Write("<br>");
        foreach(HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
        {
            Response.Write(cell.InnerHtml + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

it prints out like this..

Ali, Saleh(#82358)
PO Box: 0001
Abu Dhabi 0000
United Arab Emirates
Phone: +1234567890

Ali, Saleh(#82358)
PO Box: 0001
Abu Dhabi 0000
United Arab Emirates
Phone: +1234567890

etc...

I am trying to get it to write to a file exactly like that and am running into an issue, when I add this to the foreach statement to write the cells

```
sb1.Append(cell.InnerHtml + "<br>");
sb1.AppendLine();
sb1.Append("<br>");
```

and this after the complete loop

```
string str3 = str2.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine).Replace("&nbsp;", " ")
            .Replace("                        ", "");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\BBBBB.txt", str3);
```

When I look at the text file, it is almost looking the way it does in the webpage, but there is a lot of empty space that I have to deal with. However, if I save the html page as a text file (when running the app) from the browser it lays it out in text file exactly how it looks on the webpage.

I've tried, writing the cells innerHtml to a text file and have tried saving the cell inner text but either way, I still find myself having to replace strings.

How can I get the webpage layout to be the same when saved to a textfile?

Comment: What if you save the file with **.html** extension rather than .txt ???

Comment: I have and it looks like it does in the webpage, exactly the way I want it, but I need it to save as a text file, because I will be appending to it later on

Comment: can u not load it into a memory stream from a .txt and write it as an html after your done appending?

Comment: @CalvinSmith, the page itself is saved as an html file, but when I save it to a text file, I would still like it to maintain how it looks on the html page

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure how you want a .txt file to be both a .txt file and a .html file...?

Comment: @CalvinSmith, Sorry I been having an issue articulating what I mean lately.. What I did was created the html file so I could see how the data was looking. I wound up figuring it out lastnight. I was able to extract from the html and print it to a text file exactly the way it looks